# How to load huggingface model/resource from local disk?

Tags: local-storage, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

I am behind firewall, and have a very limited access to outer world from my server. I wanted to load huggingface model/resource from local disk.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
# initialize sentence transformer model

# How to load 'bert-base-nli-mean-tokens' from local disk?
model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
# create sentence embeddings
sentence_embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
```

I came across some comments about

> load_pretrained()

, etc. However, could not get the above problem sorted. Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure sentence_transformers is a HuggingFace library? I think you are mixing things up with transformers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, clone the model you want to load with `git clone`

In your example:

`git clone https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens`

You can of course download it from another PC and pass it, to avoid the firewall problem.

After that, simply replace the name of the model with the path of the file you
just downloaded:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
# initialize sentence transformer model

# How to load 'bert-base-nli-mean-tokens' from local disk?
model = SentenceTransformer('/path/to/cloned/git/repo')
# create sentence embeddings
sentence_embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
```

Side note: as mentioned [here](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens):

> This model is deprecated. Please don't use it as it produces sentence
> embeddings of low quality. You can find recommended sentence embedding
> models here: [SBERT.net - Pretrained Models](https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html)

Comment: thank you for your response. I want to add some extra clarification for future developer. After the cloning from git there are some more steps. First install, "git lfs" if you don't have it installed. Then got into the clonned folder. And run two commands, git lfs install and git-lfs pull. This will pull all large files. Only then it will work as expected.

Comment: Oh sorry, I probably installed that in the past and forgot about it. Anyway, I hope your problem is solved now!