# Hugging Face model deployment

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, monad-transformers, mlops

My question is related to how one deploys the Hugging Face model. I recently downloaded the Falcon 7B Instruct model and ran it in my Colab. However, when I am trying to load the model and want it to generate text, it takes about 40 seconds to give me an output. I was just wondering how we deploy these models in production then so that it gives us output with low latency. I am new to MLOps so I just want to explore. Also, what will be the charges of deploying that model? What if many users are simultaneously using this model? How will I handle that? Will greatly appreciate the response.

The code I am using is from the https://huggingface.co/tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct.

Also, I am saving the model weights locally in a Google Drive.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you want to deploy your model. It is really easy to do on AWS Sagemaker

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.session import Session
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel, get_huggingface_llm_image_uri

PROFILE_NAME = ""
ENDPOINT_NAME = ""
ROLE = ""

boto_session = boto3.Session(profile_name=PROFILE_NAME, region_name="us-east-1")
sagemaker_session = Session(boto_session=boto_session)

# get the huggingface llm image
llm_img = get_huggingface_llm_image_uri(
    backend="huggingface",
    session=sagemaker_session,
    version="0.9.3"
)

# define the model deployment configuration
deploy_config = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID': "tiiuae/falcon-7b", # model_id from hf.co/models
    'SM_NUM_GPUS': json.dumps(1), # Number of GPU used per replica
    'MAX_INPUT_LENGTH': json.dumps(3072),  # Max length of input text
    'MAX_TOTAL_TOKENS': json.dumps(4096),  # Max length of the generation (including input text)
    'MAX_BATCH_TOTAL_TOKENS': json.dumps(8192),  # Limits the number of tokens that can be processed in parallel during the generation
    # ,'HF_MODEL_QUANTIZE': "bitsandbytes", # comment in to quantize
}

# create HuggingFaceModel with the image uri
llm_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    role=ROLE,
    image_uri=llm_img,
    env=deploy_config,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session
)

# Deploy model to an endpoint
instance_type = "ml.g5.2xlarge"
health_check_timeout = 300

llm_endpoint = llm_model.deploy(
    endpoint_name=ENDPOINT_NAME,
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type=instance_type,
    container_startup_health_check_timeout=health_check_timeout, # 10 minutes to be able to load the model
)
```

Answer (score 1):

- I was just wondering how we deploy these models in production then so that it gives us output with low latency.

You can [download the model and use it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73282911/how-to-load-huggingface-model-resource-from-local-disk/73292853#73292853), to avoid any kind of latency related to Internet connection. Notice that you input has to be processed, so it is normal to take some time to give you a response. To make it as quick as possible, you have to run it on GPUs (typically dozens of times faster that CPUs).

- Also, what will be the charges of deploying that model?

You can use the models for free.

- What if many users are simultaneously using this model?

I have never experienced issues of this kind, but if you want to avoid any kind of problem, once again, you can download the model and load it from local.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am just more curious about its application in a production setup.